# Divergence of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

We say sum of two sequences , if both of them are divergent then in addition ,and subtraction  we again get a divergent series
But let us assume a sequence 
A=z
B=-z
Here z is the set of only positive integers
Both are divergent but there sum is zero on adding so can anyone tell me where I am wrong .

Comment: You're not. The sum of two divergent series can converge. It is only true that the sum of two divergent series must also diverge if all terms of both series are positive (or all terms of both series are negative).

Comment: Maybe you can restrict to adding two divergent sequences of the same sign and subtracting sequences of different signs, then it would be true.

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit clearer - you are wrong in this statement:

> if both of them are divergent then in addition ,and subtraction we again get a divergent series

That is simply not true in general, as your counter-example shows. There are specific cases where it is true: if $a_n \ge 0, b_n \ge 0 \,\, \forall n$, and $a$ and $b$ diverge, then so does $a + b$, but $a - b$ does not have to diverge.